# opencv set picture dimension

Tags: c++, opencv

Hy,

I am using OpenCV2.4.4 to develop the following application:

1. read an image in Mat format;
2. transform it to grayscale;
3. detect the face, if exists;
4. crop the face, extracting the Region Of Interest;
5. save the cropped image to file.

My question is: could I possible set a standard dimension for the saved image (width and height)?

I tried to use **resize** function, but it doesn't actually I want because saves just a part of the face.

```
cv::cvtColor(croppedImage, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
greyMat.resize(100);    
imwrite("result.jpg", greyMat);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [cv::resize](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-resize) instead:

```
cv::cvtColor(croppedImage, greyMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat result;
cv::resize(greyMat, result, cv::Size(100,100));    
imwrite("result.jpg", result);
```

See the documentation for details.